# Sending Push Notifications to Web Application without user consent

Tags: node.js, web-applications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications to my web application users on the occurrence of certain events by updating an icon with a red dot. This is similar to Facebook updating the "notification bell" icon with a dot, on receiving a message or getting a new friend request

[LINK TO EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBbA8IBZ_Kwng7NS9U5umvdQI92wSN9g/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried to send notifications to the web app, but it requires the user to "allow notifications" before sending it.

Note that, Facebook/Twitter or any other social media sites can notify users even if the user explicitly blocks all the notifications for the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Socket.io](https://socket.io/)** is quite handy for this. You can just listen/emit some events at both client and server and act accordingly (in your case, updating the "notification bell" icon)